# How to initialize local fields of a WCF proxy class on deserialization

Tags: silverlight, wcf, serialization

In my Silverlight client I have a partial class created by setting a WCF reference.  I've extended this class adding a few RelayCommand properties.  I need to initialize these properties which I would normally do in the constructor.  However it seems that the constructor is not being called, which I believe is a result of of [VTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization)  However I'm also unsuccessful in using the `OnDeserialized` attribute.

What is the prescribed way to initialize client side data members of a WCF class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample project and everything works as expected. If this code doesn't help - post your data contract and client code.

```
namespace SilverlightApplication3.ServiceReference1
{
    public partial class SomeModel
    {
        public string ExtendedProperty { get; set; }

        [OnDeserializing]
        public void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.ExtendedProperty = "Ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Service method call:

```
var proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
proxy.DoWorkCompleted += (s,e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.ExtendedProperty); //Ok
proxy.DoWorkAsync();
```